# Unable to locate newly created CouchDB database file in the default location ./data

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb

After migrating from CouchDB 1.x to CouchDB 2.x, whenever i create a new database using futon i cannot locate it anywhere on my machine including the default location ./data. Any idea on where to find it? i also ran a search for the particular file without getting any result.

Answer (score 0):

Default is `/var/lib/couchdb` according to https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.2.0/config/couchdb.html

Comment: Yes i checked in that folder already and it is not there. It seems like the /opt/couchdb/data is linked to the /var/lib/couchdb folder